# How to find a file in cmd and then piping the output in findstr

Tags: windows, batch, windows-command-prompt

I have a simple question regarding how to finding a file in cmd and then piping the output to findstr to nail down a specific file.

For example,

dir *change* /s /p | findstr "error"

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Use powershell?  It should make this easier

Answer (score 0):

two ways:

```
dir *test* /s/b

dir /s/b | findstr /i "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this file to locate files on c:\ drive using a string

dir /s/b *.* | find /i "CVE-2016-2107"